# How to give each table (or group of courses) a specific color in this HTMLTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following database design:

> Employee Table: Username, name, Job... etc
>
> Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID
>
> Employee_Courses Table: EmployeeID, CourseID
>
> Group Table: GroupID, GroupName

***NOTE: The first attribute in each table is the primary key***

I have developed a matrix that shows all employees and all courses. Since I have three groups of courses three, I need to have one table for each group of courses. I developed this matrix to view the information using GridView inside a Repeater control. Also, I developed again for entering data using the HTMLTable in C#. Everything works fine. What I need now is to give each group specific color. For example, Group#1 with Blue color and Group#2 with Yellow color and so on. I am struggling now with doing this in C#.

**So could anyone please help me with this issue?**

My code in ASP.NET and C# is as following:

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />

            <%--This SqlDataSource is for retrieving the GroupID--%> 
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [groups]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


            <%--This SqlDataSource is for retrieving the information of the employees and the safety training coruses--%>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport" FilterExpression="[DivisionName] like '{0}%'">

                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter  Name="GroupID"/>
                            </SelectParameters>

                            <FilterParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName" 
                                                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </FilterParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <%--Filtering by Division--%>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceDivision" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [DivisionName] FROM [Divisions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:Button ID="updateButton" runat="server" OnClick="updateButton_Click" Text="Update" />
```

**C#:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach (DataRowView group in dv2)
        {
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = group[0].ToString();
            //create a new HtmlTable object
            HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

            DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            int columns = dv.Table.Columns.Count;
            int rows = dv.Count;

            //table's formating-related properties
            table.Border = 2;
            table.CellPadding = 3;
            table.CellSpacing = 3;
            table.Width = "900px";

            //to get the css style
            table.Attributes["class"] = "mGrid";

            //create a new HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell objects
            HtmlTableRow row;
            HtmlTableRow header = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell;


            //for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);

            //loop for adding rows to the table
            foreach (DataRowView datarow in dv)
            {
                row = new HtmlTableRow();
                row.BgColor = "yellow";


                //loop for adding cells
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    if (j < 4)
                    {
                        cell.InnerText = datarow[j].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

                        int checkBoxColumns = dv.Table.Columns.Count - 5;
                        string fieldvalue = datarow[j].ToString();
                        string yes = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                        string courseid = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                        checkbox.ID = row.Cells[3].InnerText + "," + courseid.Trim();
                        checkbox.Checked = yes.Equals("Yes");
                        cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                    }

                    //add the cell to the current row
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                //add the row to the table
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //add the table to the page
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes the group name as a parameter and returns the desired color then call the function from either your code or markup where the color needs to be set. You could return a string of a CSS class name or any other desired display method.

```
private string GroupColor(string groupName)
{
     string returnColor = string.empty;
     switch(groupName.toUpper())
     {
          case "GROUP1":
              returnColor = "green";
              break;
           case "GROUP2":
              returnColor = "blue";
              break;
            //  More case statements as needed...
            default:
              returnColor = "orange";
              break;
      }

      return returnColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could you not do something like this?

first create a class in your style sheet for the color you want.

```
.redcell{background:#ff0000;}
```

then in your code where you're adding your cells.

```
if(Group=="mygroup")
{
  cell.Attributes.Add("class","redcell");
}
```