# How to give each HTMLTable header a specific color in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following database design:

Employee Table: Username, name, Job... etc

Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID

Employee_Courses Table: EmployeeID, CourseID

Group Table: GroupID, GroupName

***NOTE: The first attribute in each table is the primary key***

I have developed a matrix that shows all employees and all courses. Since I have three groups of courses three, I need to have one table for each group of courses. I developed this matrix to view the information using GridView inside a Repeater control. Also, I developed again for entering data using the HTMLTable in C#. Everything works fine. What I need now is to give each group specific color. For example, Group#1 with Blue color and Group#2 with Yellow color and so on. I am struggling now with doing this in C#.

**So could anyone please help me with this issue?**

My code in ASP.NET and C# is as following:

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />

            <%--This SqlDataSource is for retrieving the GroupID--%>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [groups]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


            <%--This SqlDataSource is for retrieving the information of the employees and the safety training coruses--%>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport" FilterExpression="[DivisionName] like '{0}%'">

                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter  Name="GroupID"/>
                            </SelectParameters>

                            <FilterParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName"
                                                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </FilterParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <%--Filtering by Division--%>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceDivision" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [DivisionName] FROM [Divisions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:Button ID="updateButton" runat="server" OnClick="updateButton_Click" Text="Update" />
```

**NOTE:** GroupID will be retrived from SqlDataSource1, and then will be used in SqlDataSource2

**C#:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach (DataRowView group in dv2)
        {
            SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = group[0].ToString();
            //create a new HtmlTable object
            HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

            DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            int columns = dv.Table.Columns.Count;
            int rows = dv.Count;

            //table's formating-related properties
            table.Border = 2;
            table.CellPadding = 3;
            table.CellSpacing = 3;
            table.Width = "900px";

            //to get the css style
            table.Attributes["class"] = "mGrid";

            //create a new HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell objects
            HtmlTableRow row;
            HtmlTableRow header = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell;


            //for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;
                //I need to specify the color for each group here
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);

            //loop for adding rows to the table
            foreach (DataRowView datarow in dv)
            {
                row = new HtmlTableRow();
                row.BgColor = "yellow";


                //loop for adding cells
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    if (j < 4)
                    {
                        cell.InnerText = datarow[j].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

                        int checkBoxColumns = dv.Table.Columns.Count - 5;
                        string fieldvalue = datarow[j].ToString();
                        string yes = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                        string courseid = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                        checkbox.ID = row.Cells[3].InnerText + "," + courseid.Trim();
                        checkbox.Checked = yes.Equals("Yes");
                        cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);

                    }

                    //add the cell to the current row
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                //add the row to the table
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //add the table to the page
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);

        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to solve it by doing this:

```
//for adding the headers to the table
            foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
                headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;

                //SqlDataSource DataReader Mode
                using (SqlDataReader rdrSql = (SqlDataReader)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty))
            {
                while (rdrSql.Read())
                    if (rdrSql["ID"].Equals(1))
                        headerCell.BgColor = "lightBlue";
                    else if (rdrSql["ID"].Equals(2))
                        headerCell.BgColor = "lightYellow";
                    else if (rdrSql["ID"].Equals(3))
                        headerCell.BgColor = "lightOrange";
            }
                header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(header);
```

But I failed and I got the following error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

and I don't know why. Any help please?

***NOTE:***
FYI, the SqlDataSource1 is for:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [groups]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the SqlDataSource2 is for:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport" FilterExpression="[Division] like '{0}%'">

                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter  Name="GroupID"/>
                            </SelectParameters>

                            <FilterParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName" 
                                                         PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </FilterParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266315/how-to-give-each-table-or-group-of-courses-a-specific-color-in-this-htmltable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271472/how-to-give-each-table-header-or-group-of-courses-a-specific-color-in-this-htm

Comment: how the heck is so the same ??? you copy the same code ? You are in the same class ? the same school ? the same person with amnesia :))

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this each time you add the header row...

```
header.Style.Add("background-color", "Red")
table.Rows.Add(header);
```